# Spring data - @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true , flushAutomatically = true) causing another entity not to be updated

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We have a repository that have the following update:

```
@Query(value="UPDATE Brand set name=?1 where id=?2")
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true , flushAutomatically = true)
int updateBrandName(String name, Long brandId);
```

We are experiencing a weird behavior on the following case:

```
@Transactional
public void test() {
    Brand b = brandRepository.findById(1);
    Settings s = settingsRepository.findById(2);        

    brandRepository.updateBrandName("some new name", 1);   // WILL BE PERSISTED
    s.setModifiedBy(null);  //  WONT BE PERSISTED
}
```

Another use case that works differently:

```
@Transactional
public void test() {
    Brand b = brandRepository.findById(1);

    brandRepository.updateBrandName("some new name", 1);   // WILL BE PERSISTED
    b.setSomeOtherField(null);  //  WILL BE PERSISTED
}
```

Removing the (clearAutomatically = true) solves the problem (everything is peristed)

Why the **Settings** entity is not persisted while the original **Brand** entity does when the clearAutomatically = true?

If we do need the clear automatically = true, how can we do it properly?

Comment: If this is the actual observed behaviour, that would be a bug in Spring Data JPA. Please create an issue including a reproducer.

Comment: The spring-boot version we use is 2.3.8, but i have reproduced this on 2.7.1 as well (which is the latest) so i am not sure its a bug

Comment: I don't see the relation between the Spring Boot version and the question if this is a bug. Even the latest version might contain bugs, and some of them are in there for ages.

Comment: Could I ask what "clearAutomatically = true" was added for?

Comment: To clarify, I consider the behavior described in the second example to be a bug. The first one works as designed, as detailed by Oliver in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

This works as designed. As the Javadoc suggests, `clearAutomatically` triggers persistence context clearance, i.e. calls `EntityManager.clear()`. The Javadoc of that clearly states:

> Clear the persistence context, causing all managed entities to become detached. Changes made to entities that have not been flushed to the database will not be persisted.

That's why your modification of `s` does not get persisted. I guess an explicit call `settingsRepository.save(s)` should do the trick as it merges the now detached instance to the persistence context again.